# Author extraction in newspaper example is not working

Tags: python, nlp, python-newspaper, newspaper3k

I'm trying to use newspaper3k to extract speaker names from webpages containing speeches with no luck. Following the documentation of the package, `article.authors` seems to always return an empty list.

Using the example in the docs [here](https://newspaper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

```
In:

from newspaper import Article

url = 'http://fox13now.com/2013/12/30/new-year-new-laws-obamacare-pot-guns-and-drones/'
article = Article(url)
article.download()
article.parse()
article.authors
```

returns

```
Out: []
```

Instead of the expected

```
Out: ['Leigh Ann Caldwell', 'John Honway']
```

It's not working for many other examples too.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this issue on github [485](https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper/issues/485), *newspaper3k* seems to be broken in python3, there is  a workaround mentioned in the issue if you downgrade to python2.